# implementing in app purchase on android

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading, in-app-purchase

I am in the process of implementing in purchases for my app on eclipse but Im stuck on this part where you have to call getSkuDetails

```
Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```

The android implementation guide -> http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Tells me

"Warning: Do not call the getSkuDetails method on the main thread. Calling this method triggers a network request which could block your main thread. Instead, create a separate thread and call the getSkuDetails method from inside that thread."

My only problem is I dont know how to call another thread inside my main activity or how to go about doing it since I've never done it before, thanks to anybody who can help me been stuck on this for the past week

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    connection = new ServiceConnection() {

           @Override
           public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

               mService = null;

           }

           @Override
           public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

               mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);

           }
        };


        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");

        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        bindService(serviceIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


}

public void levelTwoButtonClicked(){

    Assets.click.play(1.00f);

    new LoadIconTask().execute();

}

class LoadIconTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Long> {

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        skuList.add(inappid);
        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
        Bundle skuDetails;      

    try{

            skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);

            int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
            if(response == 0){

                ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                for(String thisResponse : responseList){

                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                    String sku = object.getString("productID");
                    String price = object.getString("price");

                    if(sku.equals(inappid)){

                        System.out.println("price" + price);
                        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                        startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));

                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SendIntentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }


}
```

Each time I run and click on my Buy level two button I get this error

```
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at com.izzymachado.framework.implementation.AndroidGame$LoadIconTask.doInBackground(AndroidGame.java:198)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at com.izzymachado.framework.implementation.AndroidGame$LoadIconTask.doInBackground(AndroidGame.java:1)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-07 20:16:26.102: E/AndroidRuntime(19783):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

line 198 is skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to make network calls on the main thread, this is due to the fact that you don't want to block the user from performing actions while this is happenning.

So, you should use an [AsyncTask](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fos%2FAsyncTask.html&ei=tbp0VYj_BYKeNsOFgfgH&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&sig2=2NmQF8TRZ76SBcvNEcp8Sg&bvm=bv.95039771,d.eXY) for this operation, which will make the network call in the background, then notify you, so you can make changes to the UI (back on the UI thread).

Comment: ok thanks alot! Im reading that AsyncTask must be subclassed, so does this mean I need to create a subclass of my Activity and implement AsyncTask there, or can I call AsyncTask on my activity ?

Comment: You don't need to subclass AsyncTask - just put it in your already existing Activity, as an Innerclass - there is an example in that doc, you can cut and paste directly.

Comment: ok I just copied & pasted it, do I call this now from my method that starts the request Im just a bit confused on how to do it.  public void leveltwobuttonclicked(){ new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3); } ?

Comment: What you have is correct.  You would just call it like that from wherever you want to use it.

Comment: hey one more question what should I put for the 3 parameters  in AsyncTask ? since I don't have any URLs

Comment: You don't need any parameters.

Comment: do you have an email I could email you at for more help ? Its still not working for me and I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong, maybe you could point out to me what I'm doing wrong if I send the code

Comment: Post the code here, I am not going to help via email.

Comment: One of the items in that line of code has not been initialized.  I am not sure which one, but that is what a NullPointer means.  Figure out which of those has not been initialized.  Oh, and don't forget to mark this answer as correct (after all this work!)

Comment: Has anyone received this: `org.json.JSONException: No value for productID` from the above code snippet? And thank you! I have been trying to get this into the right structure for sometime now. The Android docs for this are not very clear for structure.

Comment: @Cole - look at the JSON response (it is human readable).  You are not parsing it correctly (either the key you are looking for doesn't exist, or it is in another level).  Bottom line, just look at the JSON to see why the value you are looking for is missing (like the error tells you - it can't find "productID").

Comment: Thank you, it was as simple as "productID" to "productId"

Comment: Woot!  Love the easy ones.